# How to find the length of the last word in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to find the length of the last word to initially find the length of the second word in the phrase. here's my plan, If I find the length of the last phrase then in the for loop if I subtract x, it should give me the length of the second word always. This has to be done using for loop and a scanner, where the user inputs any phrase.
Basically, I need to know how to find the length of the last phrase. Thats what I need to know only.

here's my code:

```
else if (option == 2){
    int counter = 0 ;
    for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length() - x; x++){ 
        //in the "int x = 0" i need to put the length of the last word 
        // in a phrase 
        char n = phrase.charAt(x);
        if (n == x);
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.print("Second word has "+counter+" letters");
}
```

Comment: Please add input and output(expected) of the program

Comment: I just need to know the simplest way of finding the length of the last word in a phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question whether you want to find the length of *the last word* or the length of *the second word from the start* or the length of *the second last word* in a phrase. So, I've written solutions to all of these requirements. I've put enough comment in the code so that you can understand it easily.

## Length of the last word:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            int i;
            // Start the loop from the end in the backward direction
            for (i = phrase.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    System.out.println("Length of the last word: " + (phrase.length() - i - 1));
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If the loop terminated without finding any space, it means there is only one
            // word in the phrase
            if (i == -1) {
                System.out.println("Length of the last word: " + phrase.length());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good morning world
Length of the last word: 5
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good morning
Length of the last word: 7
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good
Length of the last word: 4
```

## Length of the second word from the beginning:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            int index = 0, counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
                if (phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    if (counter == 0) {
                        index = i;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                // Print the length when space has been found second time, and break the loop
                if (counter == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Length of the second word: " + (i - index - 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If there are only two words in the phrase, space will be found only once. In
            // that case the length of the second word will be phrase.length() - index - 1
            if (counter == 1) {
                System.out.println("Length of the second word: " + (phrase.length() - index - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Hello world
Length of the second word: 5
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good morning world
Length of the second word: 7
```

## Length of the second last word:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            int index = 0, counter = 0;
            // Start the loop from the end in the backward direction
            for (int i = phrase.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    if (counter == 0) {
                        index = i;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                // Print the length when space has been found second time, and break the loop
                if (counter == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Length of second last word: " + (index - i - 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If there are only two words in the phrase, space will be found only once. In
            // that case the length of the second last word (which is the first word out of
            // the two words) will be index (as the loop is running in the backward
            // direction)
            if (counter == 1) {
                System.out.println("Length of second last word: " + index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Good morning world
Length of second last word: 7
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter phrase: Hello world
Length of second last word: 5
```

Comment: Down-voter, please leave a comment about what you didn't like about this answer. A down-vote without comment is not useful for anyone.

Answer (score 2):

The length of the last word in a sentence can be obtained like this:

```
public int getLengthOfLastWord(String sentence) {
    if (sentence == null || sentence.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Split the sentence into words on space(s).
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
    return words[words.length - 1].length();
}
```

Comment: Could you show me without null, and without any built-in methods of java like substring so only the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

With only the for-loop, length of last word in the phrase:

```
else if (option == 2){
    int lastSpaceChar = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length(); x++){
        char n = phrase.charAt(x);
        if (n == ' ') { //Indicate space
            lastSpaceChar = x;
        } 
    }
    //When loop is finished, it will have the index of the last space
    //So if you take total length - last space, you'll get the last word
    int lengthOfLastWord = phrase.length() - spaceChar;
    System.out.print("Last word has " + lengthOfLastWord + " letters");
}
```

If you want the second word, you need to do the same, except find 1st and 2nd space, because characters between first 2 spaces form the 2nd word.

```
else if (option == 2){
    int firstSpace = -1;
    int secondSpace = -1;
    for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length(); x++){
        char n = phrase.charAt(x);
        if (n == ' ' && firstSpace == -1) { //Space found the first time
            firstSpace = x;
        } else if (n == ' ') {
            //FirstSpace has already been found
            //So this should be second
            secondSpace = x;
            break; //No need to look anymore, we have both spaces
        } 
    }
    //When loop is finished, you will have first 2 spaces
    //Characters between first 2 spaces is 2nd word
    int lengthOfSecondWord = firstSpace - secondSpace;
    System.out.print("Second word has " + lengthOfSecondWord + " letters");
}
```

I'm assuming you're just learning, so this will do.

Of course, you should probably do error handling and look out for edge cases in actual practice.

Comment: Hello, how would u do the same thing for the first letter in the phrase?

Comment: Index of first space would be length of first word(length between 0 to first space, which is equal to index of first space)

Answer (score 1):

To be accurate, you'll want to do more than just check for spaces between words, because if you are only looking for spaces then it is going to treat punctuation like commas and periods as part of the lengths of words. So your best bet is something like isAlphabetic().

If your plan is to loop through characters in the string (i.e. you don't want to use string functions), one very simple way (that wouldn't require you to change your code much) is to count forward through the array. The first time you find one where:

```
phrase.charAt(x).isAlphabetic()
```

is true, you know you've reached the beginning of the first "word" in the phrase.

Then you keep looking forward and when

```
!phrase.charAt(x).isAlphabetic()
```

Then you know you've reached the space between the first word and the second word. But there might be punctuation so you keep scanning forward until you're back to isAlphabetic() being true again, at which point you've reached the beginning of the second word. You now start counting characters until you find isAlphabetic() going false again (you've reached a space or punctuation). At which point you know you've reached the end of the second word, and now you can check your character count for how long it was.

This method doesn't count numbers, punctuation, spaces, and special characters as part of a phrase. So you might need to special-case it for things like an apostrophe in a contraction like "don't", but hopefully this gives you a general idea.

There are other approaches, but this is the closest to how you have your code right now. Obviously you can use String functions and get a shorter piece of code, etc, but you asked specifically for a version that conformed to your loop method.

```
int word_wanted = 2; // Want length of the second word. Or set to -1 if you want the last word.
int counter = 0; // How long is the current word
int on_word = 0; // What word number are we on
boolean in_word = false; // Are we currently in a word
for (int x = 0; x < phrase.length() - x; x++){ 
  if (phrase.charAt(x).isAlphabetic()) {
    if (!in_word) {
      on_word++;
      counter = 0;
      in_word = true;
    } 
    counter++;
  } else {
    if (in_word) {
      in_word = false;
      if (on_word == word_wanted) break; // Stop if we found the length of the word requested.
    }
  }
}
// counter now contains the length of the requested word. It can be returned
// as a return value from your method, or used for other purposes.
```